# Users unhappy with voting to close/move

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

Please see this question : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/36987/14625

I invited the 2 users to comment on this thread.

From my perspective, Code Review is there to Review working code, that code is not working.

Comment: That is certainly why CR is here. As per the FAQ: "What questions are on-topic for this site? ... 6.) To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?" There doesn't seem to be much to discuss, unless I'm missing something? It's unfortunate that the OP will not get the helping he is looking for, but that's how it goes.

Comment: "Users unhappy with voting to close/move" Users have been unhappy with the rules of Stack Exchange since the very beginning. "From my perspective, Code Review is there to Review working code, that code is not working." Yes, I full heartily agree...why do we have this discussion again? ... Oh wait, was there a comment from OP that I missed/was deleted in the mean time?

Comment: And if you think I meant "this question belongs here on CR" then it's a misunderstanding. I meant "it does belong as much on SO as it does belong on CR...and it does not belong on CR", migrating or sending it to SO would do nothing, it would just be closed there is it would be closed here. Badly phrased, sorry.

Comment: @Bobby that was indeed how I understood you, np

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bobby's comment to the question is:

> @tomdemuyt: Please no! This question does belong on SO as much as it does belong on CR. It would just be closed on SO. –  Bobby 49 mins ago

The poster clearly says (emphasis mine) "**I want that it should** reload or stay on same page with reload to same id." This means that *there is a problem to be solved*, the code does not work *as it is intended to*, one of the things in the [Don't ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/about) list for Code Review is:

> How to add a feature to or solve a problem with your code

Just because a question would be closed for "... must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved ..." on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) doesn't mean that we should accept them here. There is a reason for **why** it would be closed on Stack Overflow. We might be friendlier here than the ones on SO, but **off-topic is still off-topic.**

Answer (score 4):

There is plenty to criticize about the code: the use of HTTP GET for a non-idempotent delete operation, the use of the deprecated `mysql_query()` suite of functions, the careless use of string interpolation that could lead to SQL injection and HTML injection.

Unfortunately, the question is poorly formulated.  I can't figure out exactly what the situation is, but it's clear that the poster is asking for a problem to be solved.  There may be other fora for questions like this, but Code Review isn't it.